# Templates or tutorials for creating a title page

Tags: titles, templates, best-practices, thesis, tutorials

I am relatively new to Latex. I am writing my thesis in Latex, which has been (as you know) so much more convenient than a word processor. I am using `\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}` along with the `libertine` and `libertinust1math` packages.

But, my department has provided me with a title page template in a Word file (screenshot below), and they say I must follow the template exactly.
[image: title]

How do I go about creating a title page in Latex? Can you please recommend some Latex templates or tutorials that might help me think about how to reproduce the above snapshot from Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't the real PDF template to compare, I tried to replicate the template as similar as I can.

[image: Sample]

My code is [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bthczwcfwsqh) (perhaps not forever), and follows as well:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}           % Just for example
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\title{Thesis Title: Subtitle}
\author{Firstname M Lastname}
\date{December, 2020}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printcover}{%
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \normalsize
            \vspace{\stretch{1}}

            {\bfseries \@title}

            \vspace{\stretch{1}}
            Submitted in partial fullfilment of the requirements for the degree of\\[1em]
            Doctos of Philosophy in\\[1em]  
            Department of Hilarity

            \vspace{\stretch{1}}            
            \@author            
            \vspace{\stretch{2}}

            Fun University

            Jolly City, Silly Syaye

            \vspace{2em}

            \@date
            \vspace{\stretch{1}}
        \end{center}

    \end{titlepage}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \frontmatter % Remove numbering from frontmatter
    \printcover  % We've defined above
    
    % some stuffs
    
    \mainmatter % Start numbering
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1-50] % Just for example
\end{document}
```

### If you want the *exact* copy

If your university is *very* serious about this "follow *exactly*", maybe you can export the cover to PDF using Word and include it in your document. To do that, just use this MWE.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1]{cover}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped a fellow human being today! Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad! Please, consider marking the answer as "solved" ^-^.